# how to connect a 3rd node on a different network using bootnode to an existing permissionless/public node on GCP

Tags: validator, bootnode

I have set up a trusted node using substrate node template with 2 nodes on GCP. (a permissionless/public network A)

I would like simulate the process to add a 3rd node as a validator on a different network to connect to the network A, meaning to be able to connect using a bootnode.

I am having difficulty understanding how to setup the chainspec for the 3rd node, configure the bootnode and can't find any documentation on this.

Is there a tutorial somewhere that is available for this?

Thank you.